# Can I use an OR in regex without capturing what's enclosed?

Tags: regex, capture, regex-group

I'm using [rubular.com](https://rubular.com) to build my regex, and their documentation describes the following:

```
(...)   Capture everything enclosed
(a|b)   a or b
```

How can I use an OR expression without capturing what's in it? For example, say I want to capture either "ac" or "bc". I can't use the regex

```
(a|b)(c)
```

right? Since then I capture either "a" or "b" in one group and "c" in another, not the same. I know I can filter through the captured results, but that seems like more work...

Am I missing something obvious? I'm using this in Java, if that is pertinent.

Comment: Nice one +1 for the link to rubular

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Depending on the regular expression implementation you can use so called *non-capturing groups* with the syntax `(?:…)`:

```
((?:a|b)c)
```

Here `(?:a|b)` is a group but you cannot reference its match. So you can only reference the match of `((?:a|b)c)` that is either `ac` or `bc`.

Comment: I thought the idea was not to capture the `a` or `b` at all.  In other words, to *match* `ac` or `bc`, but only *capture* the `c`: `(?:a|b)(c)`

Comment: @AlanMoore  Is it possible to capture one and not the other in the or statement?  So I'm looking for the pattern `ac` or `ab`, but I want to output `ab` if `ab` and only 'c' is output is 'ac'.

Answer (score 37):

If your implementation has it, then you can use non-capturing parentheses:

```
(?:a|b)
```

Answer (score 9):

If your OR alternatives are all single characters - you can just use "character set" operator:

```
([ab]c)
```

it will only match `ac` or `bc` and it's more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Even rubular doesn't make you use parentheses and the precedence of `|` is low. For example [a|bc does not match ccc](http://rubular.com/r/wng2h30dLF)

Comment: what does the '!~' operator do?  I like your expression, with fewer parens, regex is messy enough already

Comment: !~ is a perlism for "does not match", it was sloppy writing on my part; fixed, thanks.

Comment: I don't get you.  The low precedence of `|` is why you *do* have to use parens.  `(?:a|b)c` matches `ac` or `bc` (the desired behavior), while `a|bc` matches `a` or `bc`.