# How to use alternation without creating capture groups?

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract URLs from text such as this:

```
this is text

bla bla bla


http://dev.pricewombat.com/d/4
http://www.pricewombat.com/d/12/Spalding-Premier-Excel-Basketball-15-Free-Store-Pickup
```

I wrote the following regex:

```
^(https?:\/\/(dev|www).pricewombat.com\/d\/[^ \n]+)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/iJ1fZ0/1

However, if you notice I'm using alternation for `(dev|www)` and because parenthesis are used it creates a capture group where I don't want one.

Is it possible to use alternation without creating a capture group?

Note that this is not the same question as this "similar question": [Can I use an OR in regex without capturing what's enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378773/can-i-use-an-or-in-regex-without-capturing-whats-enclosed)

EDIT: Apparently it actually is the same question as the one above, I simply misunderstood how the `?:` operator works.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you're wanting to use a [Non-capturing](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) group instead. By placing `?:` immediately after the opening parenthesis you're specifying that the group is not to be captured, but to simply group the expressions only.

```
(?:dev|www)  # group, but do not capture: 'dev' OR 'www'
```

Comment: Oops, apparently I completely misunderstood the `?:` operator. When I read about it I thought it meant it would exclude the contents from being in any capture group (in my case, I still wanted it in the outer capture group). Thanks.