# Optional group at the end includes excess group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a group at the end optional. But it includes one excess result.
What the right regex could look like? Would appreciate any help here.

Regex = `<!([a-z]{0,25})\|([^\|>]*)\|([^\|<>]*)(\|([^\|<>]*))?>`

Example = `<!user|123|Kirill|{"color":"rgb(255, 184, 75)"}> published <!content|456|A cool content>`

Gives the following 1st matched group, the highlighted is the excess unexpected result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pipe could be outside of the last capture group, then make that whole part optional using a non capture group.

Note that you don't have to escape the pipe in a character class.

```
<!([a-z]{0,25})\|([^|>]*)\|([^|<>]*)(?:\|([^|<>]*))?>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYrd4U/1)

[image]

Comment: Are you just saying "use a non-capturing group" for the optional group? Maybe just use [Can I use an OR in regex without capturing what's enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378773/)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes that would summarize it.